# Como chamar uma função PostgreSQL 9.1?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma função:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_2(p_vetoratributos text[], p_vetorvalores numeric[])
```

Estou tentando chamar:

```sql
SELECT  f_2('{"0","0","0"}', '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}')
```

Mas ele esta dando erro:

```sql
ERRO:  operador não existe: text >= integer
LINE 1: SELECT fosforo>=8  AND  kalcio>=9
^
HINT:  Nenhum operador corresponde com o nome e o(s) tipo(s) de argumento(s) informados.
Você precisa adicionar conversões de tipo explícitas.
QUERY:  SELECT fosforo>=8  AND  kalcio>=9
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "f_2" line 14 at IF
```

Estou achando que a forma que estou chamando a função não está totalmente certo.

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro vc precisa converter o tipo `text`para `integer`, pode fazer isso com: `cast(campo as tipo)`.

Answer (score 3):

Você expressou duas strings na chamada. Se fizer

```sql
 SELECT  '{"0","0","0"}', '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}';
```

ou

```sql
 SELECT  '{"0","0","0"}'||'ola', '{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}'||'ola';
```

vai reparar que é realmente tudo string.

Experimente com a sintaxe tradicional (nunca falha nem tem ambiguidades),

```sql
   SELECT  array['0','0','0'], array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
```

aqui o meu PostgreSQL (pg) entendeu como `text[]` e `int[]`. Se sua versão de pg não entender, aí você inclui o *cast*... No caso, inclusive, você quer *cast* para tipo `numeric`,

```sql
   SELECT  array['0','0','0']::text[], 
           array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]::numeric[];
```

Ou seja...

### Solução

```sql
 SELECT  f_2(array['0','0','0']::text[], array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]::numeric[]);
```